# Exchange on a domain controller

Tags: exchange-2010, domain, domain-controller

I have exchange 2010 installed on a 2008 R2 Domain controller. Will it create problems for exchange if I depromote the dc back to a normal domain member?

I am guessing it probably will which is why it is not a best practise to have your servers configured in this way.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/07/03/exchange-on-a-dc.aspx) is great article that describe such method of installation of Exchange. In short - there could be problems if you're not using DAG, and WILL be problems if DAG is used.